# How to acknowledge whether a document is deleted in OrientDB?

Tags: java, orientdb

I want to know whether there is a way to acknowledge the deletion of a document (object) of an OrientDB database. I am using the following query

`DELETE FROM User WHERE @rid=#1:1`

to delete the record and I can't seem to find a way to acknowledge where the object was actually deleted or not. 
When I check the response from

`statement.executeQuery("DELETE FROM User WHERE @rid=#1:1")`

for both the cases (the actual deletion of the object and the object not being present in the db) it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE SQL command returns, by default, the number of deleted records. Try this:

```
Integer deleted = db.command(new OCommandSQL("DELETE FROM User WHERE @rid=#1:1")).execute();
```

By the way this is faster:

```
Integer deleted = db.command(new OCommandSQL("DELETE FROM #1:1")).execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
try{
    ORecordId id = new ORecordId(9, 1);
    boolean deleted=new OCommandExecutorSQLDelete().result(id);
    System.out.println("Record Deleted " + deleted);
}
catch(NullPointerException e){
    System.out.println("Record not present in the db");
}
```